# subsonic 2.1 gac?

Tags: subsonic

Using SubSonic 2.1 in a web app in a hosted enironment (e.g. I don't have control over what happens on the server).

Does the SubSonic dll have to be registered in the server GAC, or can it simply be in the website bin folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can simply be in the website bin folder.